# move one column down in r

Tags: r

I want to move multiple columns down but without moving the first or other columns
for example, this is my df

```
df
v1 v2 v3 v3 v5
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4
```

I want this as a result

```
df
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  NA NA NA NA
2  1  1  1  1
3  2  2  2  2
4  3  3  3  3
```

I want to leave the first column or the second fixed, just move the other columns down.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
      mutate(across(v2:v5, lag))
```

-output

```
df1
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  1 NA NA NA NA
#2  2  1  1  1  1
#3  3  2  2  2  2
#4  4  3  3  3  3
```

---

Or another option is `base R` in a single line (no packages needed)

```
df[-1] <- rbind(NA, df[-nrow(df),-1])
```

NOTE: Both gives the expected output as in the OP's post

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = 1:4, v2 = 1:4, v3 = 1:4, v4 = 1:4, v5 = 1:4), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now I will apply a while, so that I can do it for each column

Comment: @janscastellon Please check the `base R`, `rbind`.  It is done on all the columns at once.

Comment: apply the while `i<-1
while(i<49){
  df1[-c(1:i)] <- rbind(NA, df1[-nrow(df1),-c(1:i)])
  i=i+1
}` And it worked perfect as I was looking for it, thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with reshaping and conditionals:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value=ifelse(id==1&row_number()!=1,NA,value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     v1    v2    v3    v4    v5
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4     4     4
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(v1 = 1:4, v2 = 1:4, v3 = 1:4, v4 = 1:4, v5 = 1:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
> `row.names<-`(df[c(NA, seq(nrow(df) - 1)), ], NULL)
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1 NA NA NA NA NA
2  1  1  1  1  1
3  2  2  2  2  2
4  3  3  3  3  3
```

or

```
> df[] <- df[c(NA, seq(nrow(df) - 1)), ]

> df
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1 NA NA NA NA NA
2  1  1  1  1  1
3  2  2  2  2  2
4  3  3  3  3  3
```